# What is proper way to write crossplatform macros in Clojure(Script)?

Tags: clojure, macros, cross-platform, clojurescript

I wrote some wrapper macros around one JavaScript lib (PRNG).
Then I wanted to make functionality provided by this macros crossplatform. 
(i.e. I want to have different implementation of this macros for JVM).

What is the proper way of doing it in Clojure?

Or can I just have one macros which at compile time detects if it's being used for JVM or JS and returns corresponding code?

Comment: i guess reader conditionals and `cljc` is what you need. https://clojure.org/guides/reader_conditionals . You can define different implementations of macros for different target platforms, and the compiler would read the correct version depending on what target if uses.

Comment: No, reader conditionals are not generally appropriate for cross-platform as ClojureScript macros are written in Clojure, so the platform indicator will be set to :clj, not :cljs. Note that macros are really concerned with WRITING code, not reading it (which is where reader conditionals are useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in ClojureScript, macros are written in Clojure (just as in Clojure). [Leaving aside the wrinkle of self-hosted ClojureScript.] So reader conditionals will only ever take the `:clj` branch in macro code in either case.

This is an ongoing subject of discussion. Related thread and ticket here:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure-dev/f6ULUVokXrU/3uue5okSAgAJ
- http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1750

One option is to simply write two versions of the macro, one for Clojure and one for ClojureScript. Another is to use some trick of the environment to determine which platform you are invoking the macro in the context of. There are several ways to do this. One example:

```
(def ^:private ^:no-doc cljs? (boolean (find-ns 'cljs.analyzer)))
```